# The error tag is too vague. What should we do about it?

Tags: discussion, tags

After seeing a suggested edit for the [error](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error) wiki I concluded that this tag is too vague to be useful. I checked Stack Overflow and they have specific tags for specific error types. I believe we should do the same thing as it will make the tags more useful. As of now the error tag has no real value.

What error tags should we create to help clarify the type of error being encountered?

(We already have crawl-error)

Comment: It's only 70 questions tagged here.  Why is it too vague?

Comment: It doesn't indicate what kind of error it is. Is it an HTTP error? PHP error? Crawl error? When we have tags for specific error they are useful as they allow users to monitor tags they know to answer and allow users to easily find related questions. A generic tag allows neither.

Comment: See this related discussion here: http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1265/the-error-and-error-code-tag-should-be-merged Although I don't think we should merge all errors tags into one tag as suggested there, having more specific error tags would allow for finer granularity in tagging questions, recognizing what they're about, and in searches. Therefore I'd be in favor of this.

Answer (score 3):

I support this because the [error](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error) tag is too general, and should be broken down into the *type* of error as John suggests, which would help users to be more specific about what kind of error their question is about, helping readers to more easily recognize what the question is about too, and helping to improve the search and related question results as well.

I think the [error-code](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-code) tag has been under utilized (in only 3 questions) because it's also too vague, so we should further define that as `http-error-code` (for HTTP errors that tags don't already exist) to make this tag clearer.

Then we could edit questions labeled with just the [error](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error) tag to contain more specific error tags, including:

- `http-error-code`
- [crawl-errors](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crawl-errors)
- `code-errors` (e.g., for scripting and other code)
- `application errors` (e.g., for applications, frameworks, control panels, etc... that don't already have tags)